# After running the following code I received from Metamsk Error

Tags: web3js, ether, dapps, dapp-development

```
import { useWeb3React } from "@web3-react/core";
import { InjectedConnector } from "@web3-react/injected-connector";

const injected = new InjectedConnector({
supportedChainIds : [1,2,3,4]
})

function App() {

const {active , account , library ,connector , activate , deactivate} = useWeb3React()

async function connect (){
   try{
      await activate (injected)
   }catch (err){
  console.log(err)
   }
```

}

```
 async function disconnect(){
   try{
     await deactivate()
   }catch(err){
     console.log(err)
   }
 }

 async function getBalance(wallet){
   try{
      library.eth.getBalance(wallet).then(walletBalance => console.log(walletBalance))
   }catch(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
}

 return (
     <>
     {console.log({active , account , library , connector})}

  <button onClick={connect}>connect to wallet</button>
  <p>{activate ? account :'disconnected'}</p>
  <button onClick={disconnect}>disconnected</button>
  {activate && <button onClick={()=>getBalance(account)}>get Balance</button>}
  </>
 );
}
```

ERROR: The MetaMask Ethereum provider does not support synchronous methods like eth_getBalance without a callback parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call the `library.eth.getBalance` function with a callback instead of a `.then`:

```js
library.eth.getBalance(wallet, walletBalance => console.log(walletBalance));
```